# when trying to convert html file t0 ios app i'm getting "unable to open configuration settings file" issue, what does it mean can you please explain?

Tags: ios, build

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQXbO.png)
when trying to convert html file t0 ios app, i'm getting "unable to open configuration settings file" issue, what does it mean can you please explain?

i tried many times, still i'm getting this error